# Spring LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded - when setting countLimit to 1

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

Using Spring-LDAP 1.3.1 I was trying to read the content of an LDAP and I've got the following error:

> LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded

After searching how to limit the result size, I've found that the class `SearchControls` is responsible for it.

So now my code looks like this:

```
SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setCountLimit(1);
ContextMapper mapper = new ContextMapper() {

    public Object mapFromContext(Object ctx) {
        DirContextAdapter adapter = (DirContextAdapter) ctx;
        Attributes attrs = adapter.getAttributes();
        try {
            return attrs.get("cn").get();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
};
return ldapTemplate.search("OU=system,DC=de", "(objectclass=person)", controls, mapper);
```

But still, the same error is thrown. So, it seems that the count limit parameter is ignored (I can't find the reference to `getCountLimit()` in Eclipse after loading dependency sources).

So my question is, how should I set the size limit for LDAP query using Spring-LDAP?

Answer (score 1):

The size-limit to which you refer is the "client-requested" size-limit. No matter what the client sets the value to, it cannot override the server's size-limit resource restrictions. Professional-quality servers can limit the number of entries returned in many ways, perhaps your client has run into one of the limits.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Search Best Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)

Comment: I'm sure there's a limit on LDAP server, but how to limit query size using Spring-LDAP and/or the query syntax of LDAP in Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a size limit, the server will limit the number of responses to that value. However, if there were actually more responses that could have been returned, if/when you attempt to iterate past the limit you will get that exception.

Quoting the [Javadoc for NamingEnumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?javax/naming/NamingEnumeration.html):

> In another example, if a search() method was invoked with a specified
>   size limit of 'n'. If the answer consists of more than 'n' results,
>   search() would first return a NamingEnumeration. When the n'th result
>   has been returned by invoking next() on the NamingEnumeration, a
>   SizeLimitExceedException would then thrown when hasMore() is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can change *sizelimit* parameter in /etc/openldap/slapd.conf on server size. More information you can find here http://www.ldapadministrator.com/forum/sizelimit-exceeded-problem-t14.html

2)Or you can limit your query like eq. here [Limit SQL/LDAP Query to 901 Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121147/limit-sql-ldap-query-to-901-rows)