# Limit SQL/LDAP Query to 901 Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, ldap

I have the following LDAP/SQL Query being used in an ADO.NET SSIS Package and I am trying to figure out how to limit the rows to 901:

```
 SELECT 
       displayName, 
       cn, 
       extensionAttribute5, 
       streetAddress, 
       telephoneNumber, 
       otherTelephone, 
       info, 
       department, 
       company, 
       givenName, 
       mobile, 
       physicalDeliveryOfficeName, 
       facsimileTelephoneNumber, 
       sn, 
       title, 
       mail
 FROM            
       'LDAP://OU=*****,OU=*****,OU=*****,DC=*****,DC=*****,DC=*****'

 WHERE        
       objectCategory = 'Person' AND 
       objectClass = 'User'
```

Comment: Over simplifying here possibly but Select Top 901 ...(rest or query here). This would return only 901 rows.

Comment: @SFrejofsky - I've tried this, but doesnt work. I can use that whilst using an OpenQuery Selection, but I cant use that within SSIS

Comment: Ok... Have you tried assigning a row_number() and and using that in a where clause to restrict your outcome

Comment: On a side note how are you using that statement in ssis that you are not able to use select top just out of curiosity.

Comment: exaclty as it is. It is within a DataReader which uses ADO.NET

Comment: The ADO.NET isnt the issue there. The problem with using a DataReader Task is that it does not use standard TSQL it uses WMI Windows Management Instrumentation. The language of which is WQL and is a dialect of TSQL and therefore would not work. This brings me to my next question. Is there a reason why you can not just use an ADO.NET source which would allow you to use both TOP and ROW_NUMBER as I beleive neither are part of WQL.

Comment: I'll try that just now. We have upgraded an older SSIS package and that was the way it was written.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
with x as(
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery ( 
ADSI, 
'SELECT  
  adspath,
  samaccountname    
FROM 
  ''LDAP:// ...''
WHERE 
  objectClass = ''User''
order by samaccountname
') AS tblADSI 
)
select 
      top 901
      adspath,
      samaccountname
 from 
    x
```